# How to change 2D array into 1D array in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, svc

Getting an error message,

> Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   array=[0.00127552 0.00286695 0.00135289 ... 0.00611554 0.02416051 0.00977264].
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Tried `tstArray.reshape(1,-1)` but no luck.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage.feature
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
trnImages = np.load('trnImage.npy')
tstImages = np.load('tstImage.npy')
trnLabels = np.load('trnLabel.npy')
tstLabels = np.load('tstLabel.npy')
trnidx = 20
trnImages.shape
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import tensorflow.keras as keras


def computeFeatures(image):
# This function computes the HOG features with the parsed hyperparameters    and returns the features as hog_feature. 
 # By setting visualize=True we obtain an image, hog_as_image, which can be plotted for insight into extracted HOG features.
hog_feature, hog_as_image = skimage.feature.hog(image, visualize=True, block_norm='L2-Hys')
return hog_feature
rnArray = np.zeros([10000,324]) 
tstArray = np.zeros([1000,324])

for i in range (0, 10000 ):
trnFeatures = computeFeatures(trnImages[:,:,:,i])
trnArray[i,:] = trnFeatures




ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.00127552 0.00286695 0.00135289 ... 0.00611554 0.02416051    0.00977264].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a   single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: I guess you want to create two different dimensions for each of your `for` loops, right? If this is the case, here is the problem, as you're generating a single list, and not a dataFrame, with 2 dimensions (meaning a matriz). 
Explain what you're trying to achieve with the first part of your code, so I can help you here

Comment: Post as well the whole console error so I can take a look

Comment: sorry added the start of my code witht the computeFeatures function, trying to extract features a selection of given images. added console

Comment: add the whole console error log as well, so I can understand the traces that generate this error.

Comment: thank you for replying, console posted